# RayCasting for pieces on chessboard movements Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, chess, raycasting

I have this unity script for moving my chess figures on the chessboard by dragging them. All the figures and the chessboard were downloaded from the asset store as game objects. However, each figure has a different set of moves. How can I put change color or light for the squares on the chessboard where my figure can move? Maybe, some RayCast can be used here but how exactly?
I would be very grateful for your help!

My script for pieces movements:

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;
     private Vector3 offset;
     private Vector3 curScreenPoint;
     private Vector3 curPosition;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = curPosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
```

The way my scene looks like:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at Sebastian's [Knight Jump Visualizer](https://sebastian.itch.io/knight-jump-visualizer) It is in 2D but this will give you the basic idea.